# JUnit struts 2.3.16 with Spring causing Unable to load bean org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper (globalActionMapper) exception

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, struts2

My JUnit is not working as expected. I am following this [link](https://struts.apache.org/docs/testing-actions.html) Below is the my code:

**`StrutsTest.java`:**

```
package com.test.action;

import org.apache.struts2.StrutsSpringTestCase;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy;

public class StrutsTest extends StrutsSpringTestCase {

    public void testHomePage() {
        System.out.println("Inside the method!");

        ActionProxy actionProxy = getActionProxy("hello/index.action");

        System.out.println("Right here!");
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals("Two are equal", 0, 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected String[] getContextLocations() {
        return new String[] { "classpath*:test-applicationContext.xml" };
    }

}
```

**`test-applicationContext.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <import resource="classpath:applicationContext-api.xml" />
    <bean id='homeAction'
        class='com.action.HomePageAction'
        scope='prototype'>
    </bean>
```

**`Struts.xml` snippet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

   <package name='mypackage' extends='struts-default' namespace='/hello'>
        <default-action-ref name="index" />
        <action name='index' class='homeAction'>
            <result name='success'>/WEB-INF/jsp/home/main.jsp</result>
        </action>

   </package>
</struts>
```

**`pom.xml`:**

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
          <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${struts.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**Exception:**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load bean
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper (globalActionMapper)
>   - [unknown location]  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
>     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)   at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:514)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:524)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$9.call(ContainerImpl.java:555)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:553)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.getActionMapping(StrutsTestCase.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.getActionProxy(StrutsTestCase.java:131)
>     at com.test.action.StrutsTest.testHomePage(StrutsTest.java:15)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)   at
>   junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)     at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)  at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)   at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)     at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: Unable to load bean
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper (globalActionMapper)
>   - [unknown location]  at org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider$ObjectFactoryDelegateFactory.create(AbstractBeanSelectionProvider.java:109)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
>     ... 28 more

Not sure what may be causing it. Can you provide any feedback?
Also, I want to have a separate struts file for test. Is it possible to do that? if yes, How?

Comment: location of test-applicationContext.xml? try renaming "test-applicationContext.xml" with "applicationContext.xml".

Comment: Some beans you can't make a dependency because it belongs to two different frameworks that aren't integrated.

Comment: @RomanC As per this [link](https://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-plugin.html) , you should be able to integrate spring with struts. The whole set up is working in the live web application but not just inside the JUnit.

Comment: @BhavinPanchani , I tried to do that too but no luck.